# How can I position right a Line from a SVG if I dont know the SVG size?

Tags: html, css, svg

Well, I have an SVG that has 100% width and height cuz it gets the size from his parent (bootstrap) and I need to position right and bottom two lines to get my hover working.
Im trying to do [this hover](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/26/creating-a-border-animation-effect-with-svg-and-css/) but it doesnt work when i go to a higher screen.
My code is this:

```
<picture>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1464" y2="0"></line>
    <line class="left" x1="0" y1="269" x2="0" y2="-538"></line>
    <line class="bottom" x1="478" y1="249" x2="-976" y2="249"></line>
    <line class="right" x1="468" y1="-10" x2="468" y2="807"></line>
  </svg>

  <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
  <source srcset="assets/img/examples-img/business-lg.png" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
  <source srcset="assets/img/examples-img/business-md.png" media="(min-width: 768px)">
  <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
  <img class="img-full" srcset="assets/img/examples-img/business-sm.png" alt="Business template">
</picture>
```

So the problem is that I cant position my Right and Bottom line in the SVG if I dont know the final size of the SVG and Picture element. I tried with bottom:0; and right:0; but it seems not to work with the Line element (or Im doing it wrong)
Btw I dont care about the size of the lines because I'm not animating it like in the codrops article.
Ty and sry for my english

Comment: set a viewBox and draw the lines at the edges of the viewBox.

Comment: I dont know how can that fix my problem. If I set a viewBox, i have to know the size of the viewBox right?

Comment: If you set a viewBox then you know its size, it's what you just set it to.

Comment: But my problem is that I cant set a size to the viewBox because i dont know the size. Each Picture has a size and it depends on the screen size. The web is using bootstrap.

Comment: And my point is you can use any size you like for the viewBox. Just make one up. The viewBox size and the screen size are unrelated.

Comment: And then I can keep width and height 100% of the SVG? Im new with svgs :(

Comment: The viewBox attribute values relate to the contents of the SVG and not the page the SVG is on.  I would suggest a viewBox value, but your SVG is somewhat confusing and I don't know what you were attempting to do.  You may wish to read some SVG tutorials and learn about what viewBox does.

Comment: Well, I fixed it with the viewport. Thank u, I'll read about SVGs more.

Comment: I don't think it's valid to put inline <svg> inside <picture> (see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element). You can link to svg files with a <source> element though.